# How to get custom number formats in PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to import an xlxs file that that some custom formats embedded within it. If I open the styles.xml file I can see the formats as follows:

[image]

When I am reading the data from these cells the custom formats aren't being applied, so I assume I need to do this manually with `setNumberFormat` - How can I read these custom format codes to format these values correctly?

Edit: Here is the code I am using to access the formatted value, slightly unusual as I am accessing PHPSpreadsheet classes via Laravel Excel.

```
 foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
     $value = (new Cell($cell))->getDelegate()->getFormattedValue();
     dump($value);
 }
```

Here is a dump of the results I get using this:
[image]

Item 10 should be `01099391` rather than `1099391`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell::getFormattedValue()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just tried this but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have edited my question to include the code I am using to access `getFormattedValue()`

The excel file I am using is here: https://gofile.io/d/PNvIvo
Column K has the custom formatting applied to it.